# rotate diagonal of a 2d numpy array into row

Tags: numpy

I have a 2d numpy array:

```
A = array([[1, 7, 5, 0, 5],
           [9, 1, 4, 6, 0],
           [9, 6, 1, 0, 0],
           [2, 5, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

What I want to achieve is

```
B = array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [9, 7, 0, 0, 0],
           [9, 1, 5, 0, 0],
           [2, 6, 4, 0, 0],
           [1, 5, 1, 6, 5]])
```

So basically every diagonal of `A` is a row in `B` with `0` padded. Is there any efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Or is each row of `A` a diagonal of `B`?

Comment: not it's not, each diagonal of `A` is a row of `B`, but not vice vesa

Comment: `np.diag(B,0)` is `[1,7,5,0,5]`  :)

Comment: ah right, it's like rotating 45 degrees.  nice observation. but I've tried the scipy rotate method, which gives me new cells after rotating 45 degree

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could come up with:

```
B = np.empty_like(A)
for i in range(5):
    pad_width = (0, 5 - len(np.diag(A[::-1], k=n))
    B[i, :] = np.pad(np.diag(A[::-1], k=i-4), pad_width)
```

Here is the explanation:

1. You can use [np.diag()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html). This will return the diagonal array at level k, where k is the position of the diagonal you want. If 0, it will return the main diagonal
2. However, you need to reverse the matrix first A[::-1]

If you run the code so far:

```
np.diag(A[::-1], k=0)
np.diag(A[::-1], k=-1)
np.diag(A[::-1], k=-2)
```

You obtain the following output:

```
array([1, 5, 1, 6, 5])
array([2, 6, 4, 0])
array([9, 1, 5])
```

You can see that we are obtaining the desired rows in reversed order, and without padding. This last issue has an easy solution: np.pad(), whose first argument is the vector to be padded, and the second argument is the width of the padding (before, after).

Thus, we have to set this width to:

```
(0, 5 - len(np.diag(A[::-1], k=n)) # You can change it to (0, 5 - n) and make it more efficient, but this way is more understandable
```

where n is the level of the diagonal.

And there we have it, just initialize B:

```
B = np.empty_like(A)
```

And change each vector of B:

```
for i in range(5):
    pad_width = (0, 5 - len(np.diag(A[::-1], k=n))
    B[i, :] = np.pad(np.diag(A[::-1], k=i-4), pad_width)
```

And the output is:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [9, 7, 0, 0, 0],
       [9, 1, 5, 0, 0],
       [2, 6, 4, 0, 0],
       [1, 5, 1, 6, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one vectorized solution using `np.meshgrid`:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 7, 5, 0, 5],
           [9, 1, 4, 6, 0],
           [9, 6, 1, 0, 0],
           [2, 5, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

B = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [9, 7, 0, 0, 0],
           [9, 1, 5, 0, 0],
           [2, 6, 4, 0, 0],
           [1, 5, 1, 6, 5]])

n, m = A.shape
ix, iy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(n), np.arange(m))
iy = (iy - np.arange(m)) % m
# array([[0, 4, 3, 2, 1],
#        [1, 0, 4, 3, 2],
#        [2, 1, 0, 4, 3],
#        [3, 2, 1, 0, 4],
#        [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]])


B2 = A[iy, ix]
assert (B2 == B).all()
```